# Setting xticklabels and yticklabels from subplot_kw in a polar plot

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, parameters, jupyter-lab

I am setting a polar histogram using matplotlib 3.1.1 inside a Jupyter Lab notebook.

I believed passing `xticklabels=[]` and `yticklabels=[]` in `subplot_kw` would do the same as setting `ax.set_xticklabels([])`, and `ax.set_yticklabels([])` but it turns out different. Is there any reason to this ?

Considering the following:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def prep(theta, ntheta=24):
    centers = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, ntheta + 1)[:-1]
    t_bins = np.insert((0, 2 * np.pi), 1, centers + np.pi / ntheta)
    hist, _ = np.histogram(theta, bins=t_bins)
    hist[0] += hist[-1]
    return centers, hist[:-1]

def polar_histogram_1(theta):
    centers, hist = prep(theta)
    _, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw=dict(polar=True, theta_direction=-1, theta_offset=np.pi / 2))
    ax.bar(centers, hist, width=0, bottom=0.0, edgecolor='deepskyblue')
    ax.set_xticklabels([])
    ax.set_yticklabels([])
    ax.grid(False, axis='y')
    ax.grid(True, axis='x', lw=0.5)

def polar_histogram_2(theta):
    centers, hist = prep(theta)
    _, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw=dict(polar=True, theta_direction=-1, theta_offset=np.pi / 2, xticklabels=[], yticklabels=[]))
    ax.bar(centers, hist, width=0, bottom=0.0, edgecolor='deepskyblue')
    ax.grid(False, axis='y')
    ax.grid(True, axis='x', lw=0.5)
```

And setting:

```
theta = np.random.random_sample((1, 100)) * 2 * np.pi
```

The following give 2 different outputs (the second one still has labels on both axis):

```
polar_histogram_1(theta) # no labels
polar_histogram_2(theta) # labels still there
```

[image: polar_histogram_1(theta)]

[image: polar_histogram_2(theta)]

Comment: Passing `xticklabels` to the [`PolarAxes`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/_modules/matplotlib/projections/polar.html#PolarAxes)' `__init__` method is currently not supported. If you think this is a must-have feature you can open an issue about it on github.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Thanks for that explanation, I guess it makes sense that `xticklabels` isn't implemented on `PolarAxes`.